# Behavior of rsyslog writing to a pipe

Tags: logs, crash, rsyslog

I configure `rsyslog` with an additional entry, like this:

```
*.* |/var/log/logpipes/pipe1
```

and have my own evaluation program for the messages received. This
works so far, but I am unsure, how `rsyslog` behaves if my pipe reader
crashes.

Would this block all other logging activities as well?
I have logfiles too and plan to use `rsyslog-pgsql` and I cannot
see, if `rsyslog` works with multiple threads, so, if one of them
hangs [pipe reader hangs], if these other logging threads will
continue.

Comment: Sounds to me that it would be very easy to test.

Answer (score 2):

It won't hang; I've played with rsyslog and pipes.  I have not had a look at the source or anything but I would presume it polls pipes non-block, so if they are not ready for writing, it just queues or discards the data.

As Stephane points out, the behavior is easy to test.  Create your pipe, configure rsyslog to deal with some output you can send via the `logger` command, restart rsyslog, then logger stuff and read or don't read from the pipe with `cat`.

Comment: Hi, thanks ! If you have no knowledge, your test scenario is probably wrong .... and learning by doing - a good thing, I'll do many times ;-) - is probably a slow way .... anyway, wrote a logger and pumped 25 k messages thru. Works good. Many thanks to all.